# Use foreach instead of map and grep in Perl

Tags: perl, foreach

I am trying to convert the `map` and `grep` code totally to `foreach` loop, but I am facing trouble when I do it.

Here is the array code to get the events

```
my @events = [
  {
    Sponsor => ’Saash’,
    Time => ’05:00’,
    Date => ’01-03-2021’,
  },
  {
    Sponsor => ’Saash Tech’,
    Time => ’03:00’,
    Date => ’01-03-2021’,
  },
  {
    Sponsor => ’Saash Technology’,
    Time => ’04:00’,
    Date => ’01-03-2021’,
  },
  {
    Sponsor => ’Saash Techs’,
    Time => ’05:00’,
    Date => ’01-03-2021’,
  },
];

my $time = ’05:00’;
```

Here is the code used in grep and map:

```
my $data = [
    map
    {
        my $hide;
        if ($_->{'sponsor'}) {
            $_->{'sponsor'} =~ ‘SaAsh’;
            $_->{‘sponsor'} = ‘Saash’ if $_->{’sponsor’} eq 'Saash Techs';
            if ($_->{‘time'} eq ’04:00’ && $_->{‘sponsor'} eq ‘SaAsh’) ) {
                $hide = 1;
            }
        }
        $hide ? () : ( $_ );
    }
    grep { $_->{‘time} =~ $time } @{events}
];
```

Below is the code where I have converted from grep map to `foreach`

```
my $data;
foreach my $event (@events) {
    if ($event->{‘time’} =~ ’07:00’) {
        my $hide;
        if ($event->{‘sponsor’}) {
            $event->{‘sponsor'} =~ ‘SaAsh’;
            $event->{'sponsor'} = ‘Saash’ if $event->{’sponsor’} eq ‘Saash Techs';
            if ($event->{'time'} eq '04:00' && $event->{'sponsor'} eq ‘SaAsh’) ) {
                $hide = 1;
            }
        }
        $hide ? () : ( $event );
    }
}
$data = [$event];
```

I am not getting the same output in foreach code when compared to the code of grep and map.

Can someone help where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Do you really want `@events` to have just one element, the anonymous array containing all the events?

Comment: As @choroba indicates, you're not saving the results of each iteration. You need to push the result onto an array inside of the loop.

Comment: Did this code make its way through Word or another word processor? You've got broken quotes in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```perl
foreach my $event (@events) {
   ...
   $hide ? () : ( $event )
}

$data = [$event];
```

should be

```perl
foreach my $event (@events) {
   ...
   push @$data, $hide ? () : ( $event )
}
```

---

`my @a = map BLOCK LIST;` can be written as

```perl
my @a;
for (LIST) {
   push @a, do BLOCK;
}
```

`my @a = grep BLOCK LIST;` can be written as

```perl
my @a;
for (LIST) {
   push @a, $_ if do BLOCK;
}
```

Of course, the `do` can be removed through simplification and refactoring, and the two loops can be combined in your case. After performing the above transformations and some cleanup, we get the following:

```perl
for my $event (@events) {
   $event->{sponsor} = 'Saash'
      if $event->{sponsor}
      && $event->{sponsor} eq 'Saash Techs';
}

my $data = [];
for my $event (@events) {
   next if $event->{time} ne $time;
   next
      if ($event->{sponsor}
      && $event->{sponsor} eq 'SaAsh'
      && $event->{time} eq '04:00';

   push @$data, $event;
}
```

You were only changing some of the `Saash Techs` sponsors to `Saash` in `@events`, which is why I do the fixes first. It was a bad practice to change `@events` surreptitiously like you were doing anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the answer code ?

```
foreach my $event (@events) {
   next if $_->{time} !~ /$time/;

   if ($event->{'sponsor'}) {
      $event->{'sponsor'} =~ ‘SaAsh’;
      $event->{'sponsor'} = 'Saash' if $event->{'sponsor'} eq 'Saash Techs';
      if ($event->{'time'} eq '04:00' && $event->{'sponsor'} eq ‘SaAsh’) ) {
          $hide = 1;
      }
   }

   push @$data, $hide ? () : ( $event );

}
```

Comment: Well, that doesn't even compile. Additionally, many other things could be fixed. `$data` could end up undefined instead of an array reference. It sometimes changes `Saash Techs` to `Saash` and sometimes it doesn't. It has statements that do nothing. It uses a regex match when it wants to use string equivalence. See my answer for these fixes.